# Laravel Broadcasting / WebSockets: How to run only for authenticated / logged in users?

Tags: laravel, websocket, broadcast

So I want the broadcast functionality only to be available for users who are logged in, because I use [Laravel WebSockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) (so I am hosting the broadcast service myself) and I want it to be scalable.

At the moment, every user who visits my website automatically connects to the broadcasting service, which is not necessary since only registered users make use of broadcasting features. So how do I restrict the broadcasting to authenticated users?

Comment: use private channel.

Comment: As @SmitVora has said you can use `PrivateChannel`s to limit your broadcast to only authenticated users. Is that what you are looking for? Or do you want to limit the client from even trying to connect if the user is unauthenticated?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. I already use private channels. But every website visitor does connect to my WebSocket service nonetheless. I just want authenticated users to connect to the service.

Comment: @Hillcow In that case, I think you can separate your script that connects to your web socket and include it conditionally using the `@auth` blade directive.

Comment: But at which point does it connect? I think it already connects when initiating Echo in `bootstrap.js`, so I cant really get rid of it?

Comment: Then don't initialize your Laravel Echo on public route. Assuming you're using vue, just setup Echo as a vuex state and init it in route that require it. I don't know why it's such a big deal for you to care about global Echo initialization. It won't count as concurrent either unless the user listening on specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

In your event class include

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
 return new PrivateChannel('library-section-edit');
}
```

In route/channel.php write the following

```
  Broadcast::channel('library-section-edit', function ($user, $id) {
    return auth()->user()->id === auth()->user()->id;
 });
```

library-section-edit is your channel name